# Slow react perfomance on ~2K records

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I have small ReactJS chat application, messages are stored inside global array client.chat as object with propery txt, which contains text. The problem is perfomance, on ~2K messages I have to wait for few seconds after each new message even if networking is commented out, so its simply rerendeing of HTML. I tried to implement same app in AngularJS and it has no delay at all. So where is the bottleneck here?

```
var client = {user: {}, chat: []};
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.socketio = ...
        // here i perform some network initialization and 
        // call client.updateChat when data has arrived over network
        client.updateChat = function () {
            me.setState({chat: client.chat.concat([]).reverse()});
        };
        client.addMessage = function (msg) {
            me.setState(prevState=>({
                chat:[msg].concat(prevState.chat)
            }));
        };
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
        this.state = {chat: []};
    }
    updateState(e) {
        this.setState({data: e.target.value});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <span>
                <Input socketio={this.socketio} visitorId={this.visitorId}/>
                <table>
                        <Chat data={this.state.chat} socketio={this.socketio}>
                        </Chat>
                </table>
            </span>
        );
    }
}
```

This is Input component, representing essentially input box:

```
class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {inputValue: ''};
        this.updateInputValue = this.updateInputValue.bind(this);
        this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
        this.getFile = this.getFile.bind(this);
    }
    getFile(e) {/* attachment handling */  }    
    handleKeyPress(target) {
        if (target.charCode == 13) {
            if (this.state.inputValue.length == 0) return;
            var inputValue = this.state.inputValue;
            this.setState({inputValue: ''});
            var ts = Date.now();
            var elem = {
                txt: inputValue, file: null, ts: ts, from: 'support', tsStr: formateDate(ts), name: client.user.name, attachmentName: null, dataType: null
            };
            client.addMessage(elem);
        }
    }
    updateInputValue(evt) {
        this.setState({inputValue: evt.target.value});
    }
    render() {
        return (<div className="input">
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label className="customUpload btnUpload btnM">
                            <span><img width="15px" src="images/attach.png"/></span>
                            <input onChange={this.getFile} id="fileUpload" type="file" className="upload"/>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input value={this.state.inputValue}
                               onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
                               onChange={this.updateInputValue}
                               className="textInput"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

This is chat component, representing chat itself.

```
class Chat extends React.Component {
    constructor() {super();}
    render() {
        return (
            <tbody>
            {this.props.data.map((p, i) => <Msg socketio={this.props.socketio} key={i} data={p}/>)}
            </tbody>
        );
    }
}
```

This is a single message:

```
class Msg extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (this.props.data.txt == nextProps.data.txt) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        var words = (this.props.data.txt || "").split(" ");
        // this piece of code splits this.props.data.txt by spaces
        // and converts it to array of words warr
        // ...
        return (
            <tr className={this.trStyle()}>
                <td>
                    <div className="msg">
                        {
                            warr.map((word, k) => <Word socketio={this.props.socketio} key={k} data={word.txt}/>)
                        }
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

This class is for a single word inside a message. If a word is too long, function shortened() returns abbreviated version.

```
class Word extends React.Component {
    shortened() { //....
    render() {
        return (
            <span className={this.wordClass()} onClick={this.click}>{this.shortened()} </span>
        );
    }
}
```

I have implemented adding new messages using concat() instead of push(), following perfomance guidelines from Facebook and also implemented shouldComponentUpdate to avoid txt.split(" ") recalculation. But it didn't give me any perfomance boost. Can anybody give me some more advice or idea?

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of response object which your are binding with react? we had similar issue,we had earlier 120kb size of json object which we were binding with react but later on optimize the json object and devided the json object in two part. 1. Pageload JSON object -It was having complete Json object with all fields and values(default)
2. Delta object- It was having only changed object field and it's value which we use to merge in React